# AngularJS File upload with directive

Tags: angularjs

I use angularJS directive to get file to upload and I use the directive like this way:

```
<input type="file" file-model="myFile">
```

The directive looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
                var modelSetter = model.assign;

                element.bind('change', function(){
                    scope.$apply(function(){
                        modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                    });
                });
            }
        };
    }]);


myApp.service('fileUploadService', ['$http', function ($http) {
        this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append('file', file);
            $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            })
            .success(function(){
                console.log('file upload successful');
            })
            .error(function() {
                console.log('file upload error');
            });
        }
    }]);
```

In controller:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function() {
            var file = $scope.myFile;
            if (typeof file != 'undefined' && file != null) {
                console.log('file is ' + file);
                console.dir(file);
                var uploadUrl = "/upload";
                fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
            }
        };
```

The upload works fine. I would have two questions concerning improvements of this upload:

1. how to upload more than one file - is there a possibility to upload more than one file with this directive
2. if file was uploaded - how to

Comment: I use: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Comment: I also use ng-file-upload. It's already built and it's free, might as well use it.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. how to upload more than one file - is there a possibility to upload more than one file with this directive

You must set `multiple`on your input field to be able to select multiple files. Then, your file variable will be an array of several files(if several files were chosen) instead of just a `File` object.

> 2. if file was uploaded - how to

... ?